# R: force format(scientific=FALSE) not to round

Tags: r, text, format

I have been playing around with this command for a while and cannot seem to make it work the way I would like it to. I would like format to give me the full list of numbers as a text without any rounding even when the whole number portion is large. For example:

```
format(2290000000000000000.000081 , scientific=FALSE)
[1] "2290000000000000000"
```

While what I want returned is:

```
"2290000000000000000.000081"
```

Comment: This isn't a problem in `format`, it has to do with the way R prints numbers. The number is changed before it even gets processed in `format`. I'm searching for a solution.

Comment: By the way, you can turn off scientific notation with `options(scipen = 999)`

Comment: Base R has no way to represent the number "2290000000000000000.000081" with exact precision. It is not a value you can store exactly in a double. If you do `a<-2290000000000000000.000081`, some loss of information occurs. Maybe try reading [why aren't these numbers equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) for more information.

Comment: If you do not want to do any further calculations on it, you can store it as: a = "2290000000000000000.000081"

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you can't store that number exactly using double precision.  You'll need to use multiple-precision floating point numbers.

```
library(Rmpfr)
mpfr("2290000000000000000.000081", precBits=85)
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  85   bits 
## [1] 2290000000000000000.000081
```